# Python counting file extensions

Tags: python

I am trying to print the file extension in a certain directory and the count of each extension.

This is what I have so far...

```
import os 
import glob

os.chdir(r"C:\Python32\test")
x = glob.glob("*.*")
for i x:
    print(i)

>>> file1.py
    file2.py
    file3.py
    file4.docx
    file5.csv
```

So I am stuck, I need my overall output to be...

```
py    3
docx  1
csv   1
```

I have tried to use something like i.split("."), but I get stuck. I think I need to put the extension in a list and then count the list, but that is where I am running into problems.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Make a new empty dictionary, if the extension doesn't exist add a new entry and set the value to 1, if it does already exist increment by 1

Comment: Are you sure you don't get a `SyntaxError` running the above code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count number of files with certain extension in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320731/count-number-of-files-with-certain-extension-in-python)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [os.path.splitext](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to find the extension, and use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the types of extensions.

```
import os 
import glob
import collections

dirpath = r"C:\Python32\test"
os.chdir(dirpath)
cnt = collections.Counter()
for filename in glob.glob("*"):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    cnt[ext] += 1
print(cnt)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
import os
ext_count = Counter((ext for base, ext in (os.path.splitext(fname) for fname in your_list)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import collections
import os

cnt = collections.Counter()
def get_file_format_count():
    for root_dir, sub_dirs, files in os.walk("."):
        for filename in files:
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
            cnt[ext] += 1
    return cnt

print get_file_format_count()
```

Answer (score 0):

this implementation will count the occurrences of each extension and put it into the variable c. By using the most_common method on the counter it will print the most frequent extensions first as you have in your example output

```
from os.path import join, splitext
from glob import glob
from collections import Counter

path = r'C:\Python32\test'

c = Counter([splitext(i)[1][1:] for i in glob(join(path, '*'))])
for ext, count in c.most_common():
    print ext, count
```

**output**

```
py 3
docx 1
csv 1
```