# python count number of text file in certain directory

Tags: python

I am trying to get the number of the files in a certain directory, but I want it to count only text file because I have another directory in the accounts and DS. Store file. What should I modify to only get the number of text files?

```
list = os.listdir("data/accounts/")
number_files = len(list)
print(number_files)
```

Answer (score 3):

From [Count number of files with certain extension in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320731/count-number-of-files-with-certain-extension-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa),

**Solution 1.**

```
fileCounter = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("data/accounts/"):
    for file in files:    
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            fileCounter += 1
```

**Solution 2.**

```
fileCounter = len(glob.glob1("data/accounts/","*.txt"))
```

Read about glob here [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)

Comment: is this not two separate solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your text files end in ".txt", you could use something like:

```
files = [x for x in os.listdir("data/accounts/") if (os.isfile(x) and x.endswith('.txt'))]
number_files = len(list)
print(number_files)
```

Using [`os.isfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) to ignore directories and `string.endswith()` to determine text file-ness.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative module that may work for you is [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#module-glob).

It will allow you to use wildcards so you can capture just the files you are interested in.

```
from glob import glob
filenames = glob("data/accounts/*.txt")
number_of_files = len(filenames)
print(number_of_files)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
number_of_files = sum(f.endswith('.txt') for f in os.listdir("data/accounts/"))
```

`str.endswith()` returns `True` or `False`
`True` and `False` have numeric values of one and zero, respectively.
`sum()` will consume the generator expression.